# DialogFlow CX, Is there a way to rename the start node?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Is there a way to rename the original start node used to start each flow?  I have a customer that states they are unable to use Start as an initial phrase to start the app, so they are requesting we rename the Start Page to something different.  Any Idea on how to do that? When I try to edit the page it will not let me change the display name of just the start page. [Start page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP9WW.png)

Comment: It looks like "Start", "End Flow" and "End Session" are not editable.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the node does not represent its invocation commands.

These are controlled via the training phrases for the intents of that node.

These can be edited within the Intent settings.

[image: Highlighted here]

Simply add in the phrases you want to use in there.